# Handle commands like ls -l /somedir

Tags: c, unix

My code so far handles the `ls` command when the user types it. I want to be able to handle commands like `ls -l /tmp` .
My code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(void)
{
for(;;){
char str[500];
printf("Type a command : \n");
scanf("%s",str);
char *path;
  path = getenv("PATH");
    char *argv[] = { path ,NULL};

    int status;
    int pid = fork();

        if ( pid == 0 ) {
printf("executing==============> %s \n",str);
          execvp(str,argv);
}
wait(&status);
}
}
```

Any ideas? I have to do it without `system()`.

Comment: First of all, you should use `scanf(" %s", str);` instead. Your code works because `str` and `&str`, in this case, have the same address.
When you call `execvp`, you need to pass as parameters the command you want to run and an array of strings, each one being one parameter to the command. P.S.: It is convention to start the array with the desired command. e.g. `char *argv[] = {str, "-l", "/tmp", NULL};`

Comment: Now whith `char *argv[] = {str, "-l", "/tmp", NULL};` when i type `ls` it executes `ls -l /tmp` direct.  What i want is to be able to handle commands like `ls` ,`pwd`  **and** commands like `ls -l /somedir` @LuizEduardoF.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Remember when splitting the string by spaces you'll need to handle cases like `ls -l /some/dir/name\ with\ spaces`

Comment: Why do you not just call `system(str)`?

Comment: I have to do it without `system()` @jofel

Comment: Just do what I said in my answer. Btw, what @ace told above is also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define MAX_NAME_SZ 256

int main(void)
{
char *str,*ret, *pa1, *pa2, *dtm ,*pa3;
str=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
ret=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
pa1=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
pa2=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
dtm=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
pa3=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
char ch =' ' ;
printf("Type a command : \n");

    fgets (str, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);

    if ((strlen(str)>0) && (str[strlen (str) - 1] == '\n'))
        str[strlen (str) - 1] = '\0';
    ret = strchr(str, ch);

    if (ret !=NULL)
    {
        strcpy( dtm, str );
        sscanf( dtm, "%s %s %s  ", pa1, pa2,pa3  );
        }

    char *path;
     path = getenv("PATH");

    int status=2;
    int pid = fork();

    if ( pid == 0 ) {
        if (ret !=NULL){
          char *argv[] = { path ,pa2, pa3 ,NULL};
              execvp(pa1,argv);

                }
        else {
          char *argv[] = { path ,NULL};
          execvp(str,argv);

        }
    }
    wait(&status);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `execvp` system call expect as its parameters a string with the command and an array of strings starting with the command, followed by its parameters, one by one, and ending with a NULL string.

In your case, it would be:

```
char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", "/tmp", NULL};
```

Remember that this piece of code is just an illustration of what is behind the scenes. You need to construct `argv[]` based on the user's input.

You can combine `strchr()` to tokenize your input (looking for blank spaces) and then using `sscanf` to read one part of the string. Then you have to update the input pointer to the value returned by `strchr()` + 1 and use `sscanf()` to read the next part of the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this and comparable things easily with [`system(str)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system).

It forks, calls `execl("/bin/sh", "sh". "-c", command, (char *) 0);` and returns after the command has completed.

As it calls the shell, it support also the shell built-ins.

Comment: I have to do it without `system()`.

Comment: using `system(command)` causes your program to stop at that point and wait while `command` is executing. Doing it with `fork()` allows your process to create a child and use the child PID to run another program for you, therefore the main program doesn't have to wait for the child to exit if it wants to do something else. Also, you should consider the effects of `execvp()` system call.

Answer (score 0):

Use "system" function for the same. 
system(str) should probably work.
This function creates a separate thread, executes the command provided to it.
See 'man system' for details of it.

Comment: I have to do it without `system()`.